# How do I read from a custom file I added to my application at startup in IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic3

I need to read a file which I added to my application codebase in IONIC but I have an issue location this file. How do I locate this needed file?

Comment: Are you referring to how to get the `app root` or any other .ts file importing?

Comment: I want to read a json file and insert it into an sqlite db. The json file comes with the app

Answer (score 0):

You can put that file in assets folder. From there you can access.

Comment: the assets folder in question, is it in the source folder or in the www folder. How then do I read this file. It is a JSON file.